# How to configure C++ relative path of include file for VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Include file of relative path in my c++ project , but i have no idea how to configure in vscode. I am a vscode beginner.

I try to configure in c_cpp_properties.json like this.

```
"includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${workspaceRoot}/../",
                "${workspaceFolder}/../"
            ],
```

the relative path include file like this:

```cpp
#include "../mxnet_op.h"
#include "../operator_common.h"
#include "../tensor/broadcast_reduce_op.h"
```